# Spring Hibernate two different DAO connections

Tags: hibernate

I have one common project that is dependent to an application called application1. I configured in this way the xmls that each project has a distinct jdbc properties file ( different filename ), which directs to different database. Postgres and MySQL. I created the following snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml", "/common-applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class AppTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    @Resource(name = "testDao")
    private IDAO dao;//Traces testDao, which originates in common package
    @Resource(name = "testApplication1Dao")
    private IDAO daoApplication1;//Traces dao from application1 package
    @Test
    public void AppContextTest(){
        SessionFactory sf1 = dao.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
        SessionFactory sf2 = daoApplication1.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
```

1. The classes TestDao and TestApplication1Dao, are extending IDAO.
   Common interface.
2. testApplication1Dao->Postgres, configured in
   applicationContext.xml and in pgsql.jdbc.properties
3. testDao->Mysql, configured in common-applicationContext.xml and in
   mysql.jdbc.properties.

Why debugging with eclipse, I see that dao and daoApplicatio1 are same objects? Should they?
How can I print on screen, the connections and properties behind each of the dao objects?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT(1)**

From common project:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository("testDao")
public class TestDao extends AbstractDao {}
```

From application1 project:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import gr.org.infrastructure.common.db.AbstractDao;
@Repository("testApplication1Dao")
public class TestApplication1Dao extends AbstractDao {}
```

and the AbstractDao is an extension of IDAO ( interface ), nothing bizzare...:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public abstract class AbstractDao implements IDAO {
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    private boolean rollbacked;

    public AbstractDao() {
        super();
        this.rollbacked = false;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently solved the problem and I can have concurrently two seperate connections live in the spring/hibernate app. In case anyone is interested drop me a note.